# Python, password for database

Tags: python, database, passwords

I'm doing simple database for classes and I have problem with password function. I can't figure out why it is asking for setting up the password every time. I think the problem is with reading if it's already in base but I don't know how to fix it.

```
import shelve
global base,pas
global magazine_base
def load_data():
    global base
    global magazine_base
    magazine_base = shelve.open('magazine_base')
    if magazine_base.has_key('base'):
        base = magazine_base['base']
        if not base:
            base = []
    else:
        base = []
        magazine_base['base'] = base

def enterpass():
    global base,pas
    epas=raw_input("Enter password to acces database")
    for entry in base:
        while True:
            if epas == entry['pas']:

                break
            else:
                print "Password incorrect"  

def password():
    global base,pas
    global magazine_base
    load_data()

    is_firstopen = True

    if 'pas' in base:
        is_firstopen = False
        enterpass()
    if is_firstopen:
        while True:
            pas=raw_input("This is the first start of database.\nPlease enter the password, min. 5 characters: ")
            if len(pas)>5:
                break
                base += [{'pas':pas}]
                magazine_base['base'] = base
                magazine_base.close()
                print "Password set"
            else:
                print "Password too short"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the prompt asking for a password in an infinite loop.

Comment: I simplified it to:
if 'pas' in base:
        enterpass()
    else:
        print "This is the first start of database.\nPlease enter the password, min. 5 characters: "
        while True:
            
            pas=raw_input()
            if len(pas)>5:
                break
                base += [{'pas':pas}]
                magazine_base['base'] = base
                magazine_base.close()
                print "Password set"
            else:
                print "Password too short, please type again: "   
But still the same, probably pass is not read or saving properly

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at this function:

```
def enterpass():
    global base,pas
    epas=raw_input("Enter password to acces database")
    for entry in base:
        while True:
            if epas == entry['pas']:
                break
            else:
                print "Password incorrect"
```

Apparently, base is a list that contains entry's. Each entry will be a dictionary that has a key 'pas'. If the 'pas' entry matches the user's password, the password is valid. I think if none matches the password is wrong. That isn't what the code does, but try this instead:

```
import sys

def enter_password(base):
    """Prompt the user for a password, and validate it against the 
    passwords stored in the entries in base. Permit three tries 
    before terminating the application."""

    from getpass import getpass

    for tries in range(3):
        userpw = getpass("Enter password to access database: ")

        for entry in base:
            if entry['pas'] == userpw:
                return

        print "\nInvalid password!\n"

    print "\nToo many failed password attempts. Goodbye!"
    sys.exit(1)
```

You could call it like this:

```
enter_password(base)
```

Comment: Im sorry I don't know how to implement this to my code, im trying but Im receiving some errors about global variables and different ones. And anyway I dont understand from where it takes correct password, how to set te password

Comment: I don't know where it gets the correct password, either! I was looking at your code, assuming that you knew the password was stored inside the `base` data. (The `getpass` call collects a password from the user, but what should it be compared against?)